# C# how to fix this

Tags: c#

I have a error that I don't no how to fix.  I would perfer the answer in code.  This is the error, Error    1   No overload for 
'turnToVideoToolStripMenuItem_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' 
C:\Users\kinoa\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Armored Animation Studio\Armored Animation Studio\main.Designer.cs 259 56  Armored Animation Studio.

This is the code,

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using NReco.VideoConverter;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;

    namespace Armored_Animation_Studio
    {
    public partial class main : Form
    {
    public Point current = new Point();
    public Point old = new Point();
    public Graphics g;
    public Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
    public List<Image> Animation = new List<Image>();
    public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        p.SetLineCap(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round, 
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round, 
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashCap.Round);
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            current = e.Location;
            g.DrawLine(p, current, old);
            old = current;
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        old = e.Location;
        if(radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            p.Width = 1;
        }
        else if(radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            p.Width = 5;
        }
        else if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            p.Width = 10;
        }
        else if (radioButton4.Checked)
        {
            p.Width = 15;
        }
        else if (radioButton5.Checked)
        {
            p.Width = 30;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();
        if (cd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            p.Color = cd.Color;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void radioButton7_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
        panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, 
     panel1.Height));
        Animation.Add(bmp);
    }


    private void turnToVideoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs 
    e, string [] args)
    {
                    Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i " + args[0] + " " + args[1];
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        if (!proc.Start())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error starting");
            return;
        }
        StreamReader reader = proc.StandardError;
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ffmpeg -i <imagefile> -vcodec mpeg4 out_movie");
        }
        proc.Close();
    }


}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Remove `, string[] args` from turnToVideoToolStripMenuItem_Click declaration.

Comment: Why did you add , string [] args at the end of the event?

Answer (score 1):

Change the method signature:

```
private void turnToVideoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string [] args)
```

to:

```
private void turnToVideoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Would take care of the compiler error, but you are left with getting to the data that you expected to be in args.  What are you expecting to be passed in that last parameter?